# How is it possible to navigate to a location which doesn't show up through "lsblk"?

Tags: linux, mount, partition, lsblk

I'm on RHEL 7.

`lsblk` provides the output below.

```
[root@integrator7 /]# lsblk
NAME                               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                                  2:0    1    4K  0 disk 
sda                                  8:0    0  100G  0 disk 
├─sda1                               8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2                               8:2    0 56.5G  0 part 
  ├─osvg-root                      253:4    0   15G  0 lvm  /
  ├─osvg-home                      253:5    0  4.7G  0 lvm  /home
  ├─osvg-swap                      253:6    0    8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─osvg-opt                       253:7    0  9.3G  0 lvm  /opt
  ├─osvg-var_log_audit             253:8    0  2.8G  0 lvm  /var/log/audit
  ├─osvg-var_log                   253:9    0  4.7G  0 lvm  /var/log
  ├─osvg-var_tmp                   253:10   0  2.8G  0 lvm  /var/tmp
  ├─osvg-tmp                       253:11   0  4.7G  0 lvm  /tmp
  └─osvg-var                       253:12   0  4.7G  0 lvm  /var
sdb                                  8:16   0  200G  0 disk 
└─sdb1                               8:17   0  200G  0 part 
  ├─vgdb-docker_lv                 253:0    0   30G  0 lvm  /var/lib/docker
  ├─vgdb-vgdb--log_lv              253:1    0  144G  0 lvm  /log
  ├─vgdb-vgdb--mnt_lv_10.5.134.162 253:2    0   17G  0 lvm  /mnt/10.5.134.162
  └─vgdb-vgdb--data_lv             253:3    0    9G  0 lvm  /data1
sr0                                 11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

But I can navigate to `/data` directory which doesn't show up through `lsblk`. I have two questions:

1. Why `/data` doesn't show up through `lsblk` command?
2. How can I get rid of `/data` directory?

Comment: lsblk shows block devices. Why do you think /data is the mountpoint for a block device?

Comment: Is it not just a directory on `osvg-root`? What does `ls -l /` say? Could it be as simple as `rm -rf /data`

Comment: @ClausAndersen: Thanks a lot for the tip. I'm new to linux. Your tip resolved the issue

Answer (score 2):

Removing directories (regardless of where they are mounted) can generally be done through `rm -rf foo`. If it's owned by `root`, then you may need `sudo`.

Other than that, I think it's worth mentioning something about mount points.  `lsblk` gives you where specific disks/partitions exist in your filesystem.  If something isn't listed there, it's usually part of a parent.  In your case `/data` might be mounted under `/`.  But that's not necessary true.

Use the command `mount` to get a full list of what's mounted.  You'll see your `lsblk` mount points listed, but you'll see non-disk mount points too.

Here's an example of what you could see (I've added indenting to make it easier to read):

```
user ~ $ mount
/dev/sda1       on /     type ext4
/dev/sda2       on /home type ext4
sysfs           on /sys  type sysfs
proc            on /proc type proc
tmpfs           on /run  type tmpfs
/tmp/debian.iso on /mnt  type iso9660
```

In this case we have two disk-mount points.  You'll see those in `lsblk`.  That means everything on `/` is on `/dev/sda1` unless something is mounted more specifically.  For instance `/home` is on `/dev/sda2`.

`tmpfs` is the next simplest type to explain.  This is a filesystem which exists in your RAM.  If you power off your machine: poof, it's gone.  Writing temporary files to a `tmpfs` mount like `/run` will perform faster than writing it to disk, especially on non-solid-sate disks.

You may have some experience with `iso` files.  As a teenager I used to keep some rewritable CDs around in case I needed to "mount" an iso.  I'd burn it to CD, then read the CD to browse the filesystem.  But you can also simply `mount debian.iso /mnt` to browse it on your system.  Now this specific file-type appears as a directory in your filesystem.

`sysfs` and `proc` types are special mountpoints used by the kernel.  You can browse `/proc` as if it were a filesystem, but the info there is actually info about current processes running on your machine.  None of that is on a physical disk.

To answer your question directly:

> Why /data doesn't show up through lsblk commnad?

`/data` is either a directory on `/dev/sda2` or it's some other type whether `iso`, `tmpfs` or something else.  Check out `mount` to be sure.